# Detect Textbox Change Using JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Using VS2012 to create a web application in VB, I have the following issue:

I create a asp:CalendarExtender that populates a asp:TextBox.  This Textbox has the property Enabled="False" assigned to it.  Once the asp:CalendarExtender has been called it will place a date in the TextBox in the format 'Sept 1 2000'.

I now want to use JQuery to detect this change.  I have come across many examples which rely on a text change using the keyboard or a Blur, but none of these work.  I have even attached a JQuery event to the button that triggers the Calendar to pop-up that removes the 'Enabled=False' property of the asp:TextBox [My train of thought was to remove the enabled property, allow the JQuery to detect a pasted change, then disable the textbox again]

Any ideas or suggestions gratefully received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need `Enabled="False"` on the TextBox, or would `ReadOnly="True"` suffice? Because the CalendarExtender will not pop up when you click the TextBox if the TextBox isn't enabled.

You could do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function alertChanged() {
    alert("Text changed.");
  }
</script>
```

With:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbxCalTest" runat="server" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="calendarTest" runat="server" TargetControlID="tbxCalTest"
  OnClientDateSelectionChanged="alertChanged"></ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
```

Comment: Thank you timbck2.  It appears that the parameter `OnClientDateSelectionChanged` was the key to this issue.  It didn't matter if the asp:TextBox had the parameters `Enabled="False"` or `ReadOnly="true"` as I am using a button to call the CalendarExtender control, but a useful tip nonetheless.